# How to do dependency injection on demand with a facade?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a web services facade like this:

```
interface MyWebServices
{
    ReportsService.Conversion[] Conversions();
    ExportService.Advertiser[] ExportAdvertisers();
}

public class MyWebServices : IMyWebServices
{
    private string apiKey;

    public CakeWebService(string apiKey)
    {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public ExportService.Advertiser[] ExportAdvertisers()
    {
        var service = new ExportService.export();
        int advertiserID = 0;
        var advertisers = service.Advertisers(this.apiKey, advertiserID);
        return advertisers;
    }

    public ReportsService.Conversion[] Conversions()
    {
        var target = new ReportsService.reports();
        DateTime from = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
        DateTime to = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        int affiliateID = 0;
        int offerID = 0;
        var conversions = target.ConversionExport(this.apiKey, from, to, affiliateID, offerID, false);
        return conversions;
    }
}
```

Each method creates an instance of a web service and then configures it before calling.

I'd rather have my UnityContainer do this configuration, but I'm left wanting something like "**on demand method injection**"...

I'm thinking this might be a good candidate to use Interception extension, but I have no way to know if this really is a scenario works - is this a reasonable way to go?

Answer (score 0):

The solution looks very simple to me, why not just create `IReportService` and `IExportService` and let unity inject the concrete implementation to the serivce, and then refactor your classes slightly to look like this:

```
public interface IExportService
{
    ExportService.Advertiser[] ExportAdvertisers();
}

public class ConcreteExportService : IExportService
{
  public ExportService.Advertiser[] ExportAdvertisers()
    {
        var service = new ExportService.export();
        int advertiserID = 0;
        var advertisers = service.Advertisers(this.apiKey, advertiserID);
        return advertisers;
    }
}

public interface IReportService
{
    ReportsService.Conversion[] Conversions();
}

public class ConcreteReportService : IReportService
{
    public ReportsService.Conversion[] Conversions()
    {
        var target = new ReportsService.reports();
        DateTime from = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
        DateTime to = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        int affiliateID = 0;
        int offerID = 0;
        var conversions = target.ConversionExport(this.apiKey, from, to, affiliateID, offerID, false);
        return conversions;
    }
}

public class MyWebServices : IMyWebServices
{
    private string apiKey;
    private  IExportService _exportService;
    private  IReportService _reportService;

    public MyWebServices(
        IExportService exportService,
        IReportService reportService)
    {
        this._exportService = exportService;
        this._reportService = reportService;
    }

    public ExportService.Advertiser[] ExportAdvertisers()
    {
       return this._exportService.ExportAdvertisers();
    }

    public ReportsService.Conversion[] Conversions()
    {
       return this._reportService.Conversions();
    }

    public CakeWebService(string apiKey)
    {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }      
}
```

Comment: +1, but why you still doing `new ExportService`? It's a good candidate for Constructor Injection.